# How can I pass in the Service Connection name to a YAML pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have several teams with several QA environments that need to be deployed to.

I am using the [ServiceFabricDeploy@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/service-fabric-deploy?view=azure-devops) task to deploy but I can't find a way to change the Service Connection during the deployment.

The input has to be valid during compile time so I can't use a variable macro ( i.e. $(connectionName) is blank durin compile ).
The input has to change based on the value passed in from the UI, so if I use template expressions (i.e. ${{variables.connectionName}}) ) they pass the compile but turn to blank during runtime.

How can I pass in the Service Connection name to a YAML pipeline?

Comment: Try considering [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#passing-parameters)... ${{ parameters.name }}

Comment: Parameters are evaluated before variables are set so they start as empty, which is not a valid ServiceConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more thorough answer to this question can be found in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline

Specifically these two paragraphs:

"This ordering helps answer a common question: why can't I use certain variables in my template parameters? Step 1, template expansion, operates solely on the text of the YAML document. Runtime variables don't exist during that step. After step 1, template parameters have been resolved and no longer exist.

It also answers another common issue: why can't I use variables to resolve service connection / environment names? Resources are authorized before a stage can start running, so stage- and job-level variables aren't available. Pipeline-level variables can be used, but only those variables explicitly included in the pipeline. Variable groups are themselves a resource subject to authorization, so their data is likewise not available when checking resource authorization."

All this means is you aren't able to dynamically select which connection you can use at the job and stage level because the resource check occurs before your dynamic selection can fully qualify.

As the reader, your next question might be "How can I choose a dynamic variable group at the pipeline level?" If you're using Azure Devops, you can create a classic pipeline with a single task that invokes your YAML release pipeline, specifying which variable group to reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: I'm going to re-mark this as the proper and appropriate answer. Thanks for the work.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was not using variables correctly. I was trying to pass them in through parameters. What I needed to do was use the variable macro directly.
This works:

```
- task: ServiceFabricDeploy@1
  inputs:
    applicationPackagePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\drop\pkg'
    serviceConnectionName:  $(connectionName)
 ... etc ...
```

Comment: I'd like to add that this works under certain conditions and not others. The issue is the pre-compiler is validating Azure RM Connections and Service Fabric Connections. They must be valid names or be blank.

Comment: I'm clueless how are you achieving this Could you expand on this? I'm hitting my head against this brick wall.
variables:
    - name: Connection
      value: SvcConnectionValue
    jobs:
    - job:
      steps:
      - task: ServiceFabricDeploy@1
        displayName: 'Deploy/Upgrade Service Fabric Application'
        inputs:
          applicationPackagePath: 'ServiceFabricPkg/x64'
          serviceConnectionName: $(Connection)

Comment: @Luminous, you may not want to use the plain word 'Connection' as a variable name. It may be reserved in some way and that may be interfering. After that, I would check you Azure Dev Ops Project for a Service Connection named 'SvcConnectionValue'. Then make sure that Service Connection is marked as "Usable by Pipelines" (I forget the exact name of the checkbox).

Comment: $(Connection) isn't a reserved keyword. I found to actually get it working you want to use this syntax `${{variables.Connection}}`. That makes the template validation pass.

Comment: That syntax <code> ${{}} </code> is evaluated during the percompile stage. The syntax <code> $() </code> is evaluated during runtime. There may be something in your pipeline that complicates the runtime evaluation. I'd have to see the whole thing to be sure.

Comment: If we just RTFM then we'd understand why this is such a pain. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline I added an answer with a solution referencing this link.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#yaml) as on 29th June, 2020,

> Service connection cannot be specified by variable

Comment: I don't know how they are referring to it but the name can be passed in a variable. I am doing it in several pipelines. What the problem is - there are a couple of inputs that are validated by the pre-compiler. Azure RM Connections and Service Fabric Connections must be valid (or blank) in the pre-compile stage. See my answer above for how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Nitin's response, this used to work in our Classic UI-defined release pipelines - we pass $(AzureSubscription) to a number of Azure App Service Deploy tasks, and the service connection is appropriately selected.

A few days back I had to make a change to a single deployment task to modify an artifact path, and *only this* task started failing until I took the variable out and manually specified the service connection.

I suspect that existing pipelines may continue to work until they're modified. I'll be doing some experimentation to validate this.